# Pushing to an array does not update view list via ng-repeat directive

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a simple `ng-repeat` directive implemented in my `index.html`

```
<div ng-repeat="item in itemCollection">
    {{item.name}}
    {{item.date}}
    ...
</div>
```

Im trying to add a new item in the array using the `push()` method.

```
$scope.itemCollection = [];

$scope.someFunction = function(){
    var o = {};
    //do stuff here.
    o.name = name-fromDoingStuff;
    o.date = date-fromDoingStuff;
    ...

    $scope.itemCollection.push(o);
}
```

`itemCollection` gets updated. I confirmed this using `alert()`

```
alert($scope.itemCollection[0].name); 
alert($scope.itemCollection[0].date); 
... 
alert($scope.itemCollection[1].name); 
alert($scope.itemCollection[1].date); 
...
```

But the list displayed in view does not get updated. I already tried using `$scope.$apply` but it's still the same. What could I be doing wrong?

**EDITED** Added additional info:

The `div` is inside `ng-controller`

```
<body ng-app = "grabbingSystem" ng-controller = "mainCtrl">
    <div class = "center-wrap">
        <ui-view></ui-view> //I'm using angular-ui-router
    </div>
</body>
```

The `div`is not part of a nested `ng-repeat`

**EDITED** Added additional Info:

All the pages in the config are assigned to the same controller.

```
.config([
        '$stateProvider',
        '$urlRouterProvider',
        function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

            $stateProvider
                .state('list', {
                    url: '/list',
                    templateUrl: 'tickets/_ticketsList.html',
                    controller: 'mainCtrl',
                    resolve: {
                      postPromise: ['tickets', function(tickets){  
                        return tickets.DBgetAll();
                      }]
                    }
                })
                .state('grab', {
                    url: '/grab',
                    templateUrl: 'tickets/_ticketsGrab.html',
                    controller: 'mainCtrl'
                })

            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('list');
        }

    ])
```

Comment: Is this the complete code? Do you perhaps have a nested controller or a nested ng-repeat?

Comment: Is your div inside ng-controller ?

Comment: Updated the post for additional information to answer your questions. Thank you.

Comment: your code is showing a controller on the body tag.  do you have a second controller being assigned in the config files for ui-router for the different views?

Comment: Updated the post for additional information to answer @Claies question.

Comment: so not only are you using the same controller class for each state (bad idea, they aren't the same instance object even though they are the same class), you are doubling up on the controller, declaring it outside the ui-view and a second time within the ui-view.  This is certainly going to give you unexpected results.

Comment: @Claies I did not know that. So what do you suggest?

Comment: honestly there is too much missing information in the bits and pieces of the code you've added to the question to know what the code is really doing in order to create a working example.  The suggested answer works, but obviously without the ui-router component.  To start with, it's never a good idea to use a single "master controller" for everything, since every ui-view creates it's own instance of the controller and you end up not only with code irrelevant to the view, but also the confusion of figuring out what is really being shown on each view.

Comment: I will try to separate the controller for each state. I made both states have the same controller so I can pass variables between them.

Comment: secondly, the `ng-controller` on the body tag serves no purpose, unless you implicitly need a controller for some code that is inside the body but outside the `ui-view`. even then, the controller for that content is better locally around it's content div.

Comment: yeah you can't pass data between them that way, since they each have their own instance of that controller.  If it appeared that they both had the same data, it was probably only due to them both having run the controller's initialization code, but changes from one state wouldn't affect the other state.

Comment: sharing data between states is best done through a service, or $broadcast / $emit.

Comment: *technically*, if neither state had a controller, they would both be sharing the controller from the body tag, and would indeed be sharing data, but that's an anti-pattern, it ends up being a big monster controller that does everything and is extremely hard to debug, besides violating the Single Responsibility Principle.

Comment: Thank you for you insight @Claies Yes service is the way to go. I'll work on it right away and post my  updates.

Comment: Better separate all functionalities on each state in different controllers to make them more manageable and easier to debug.

Comment: "If it appeared that they both had the same data, it was probably only due to them both having run the controller's initialization code, but changes from one state wouldn't affect the other state." 

This makes sense. Thats why when i explicitly initiate the value of `$scope.itemCollection` its get displayed. @Claies

Comment: I'm glad we could find the root of the problem.  Good luck with the new refactor! :)

Comment: @Claies I was able to separate the the functionalities of each state by giving each a separate controller. Removed the controller declaration in the body tag. I passed date via service (.factory). Everything is working fine now. Thank you so much for your help investigating the problem. You can edit the title of this question if you want to better guide other readers.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code It is working perfectly fine just few minor changes.

http://jsbin.com/qirafa/1/edit?html,js,output

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainController">
<div ng-repeat="item in itemCollection">
  {{item.name}}
  {{item.date}}
</div>
</body>
```

**Javscript**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller("MainController", function($scope) {
$scope.itemCollection = [];

$scope.someFunction = function(){
    var o = {};

    o.name = "a";
    o.date = "b";

    $scope.itemCollection.push(o);
};

$scope.someFunction();

});
```

Check your ng-repeat should be inside proper controller.

and you should call the function which adds the item to array.

Comment: Did you just add an initial value to itemCollection? `$scope.itemCollection = [{"name": "x", "date": "y"}];` If yes, why?

Comment: the `ng-repeat` is inside the controller. The function that adds item to array is called properly.

Comment: It's just example you can remove it.

Comment: Check I just changed fiddle and code. it is still working.

Comment: @jimx Can you create fiddle or jsbin of your code that will be good.